# C930 Webcam not show h264 stream

Tags: windows, webcam, directshow, logitech, graphedit

I'm working on capture video using the Logitech C930. Currently on Windows 8.1 and use the H264 stream from the webcam it self.

However on some PC the H264 Stream not show. I understand that C930 use UVC 1.5 and only appear in Windows 8.

Any idea how to make h264 stream visible ?

Here is the pc have problem

[image]

Here is the pc that working

[image]

Comment: The machines without H.264 might have Logitech driver installed, and those with H.264 might use the stock Microsoft's with UVC 1.5 support.

Comment: they're both Logitech Drivers , Not working : https://imgur.com/3QKe3L5 Working : https://imgur.com/6C2kuhX